# android: how to trigger a service globally by special action?

Tags: android

I want to write a screen capture app, but I don't know how to trigger my app globally by special action such as shaking the device or long press a button or anything else. Which means bring up my app under any app any time. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Since you cannot write a screen capture app, I would think that you have bigger problems than lacking a trigger mechanism.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, I can imaging that. Hope I can get things done with help of experienced guys here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a reciever for that.  For example, if you wanted the app to start activity MyReciever when the phone boots up, you could do the following:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">

        <intent-filter >

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But SCREEN_ON or BOOT_COMPLETED is not when I want to do the screenshot. I would like to bring it up when I shaking the device or long press some button, which will make a desired screen shot. I did not find such kind of action under `android.intent.action` Any better suggestions?

Comment: I believe you're able to create your own actions: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/action-element.html

Comment: Thanks, I think that's what I am looking for. I will test with it and report about it later.

Comment: Hello again. Meet some problem. Let's say I have the xml code as: `<action android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.LongPressBack" />`, then where and how should I write the java code for the action?